# Как сохранить HICON в PNG формат на C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, icon

Собственно, необходимо вытащить иконку из приложения, и сохранить её в png формат, желательно без использования gdi+.
Вытаскиваю иконку из приложения так:

```
HICON hIconLarge, hIconSmall;
ExtractIconExA("blabla.exe", 0, &hIconLarge, &hIconSmall, 1);
```

Далее всё очень сложно, пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Не знаю, что есть в этом HICON'e, но сам по себе это ведь ico файл с несколькими картинками в разных разрешениях. Если можно программно обращаться к внутренним картинкам, то можно и состряпать массив, сохранить затем его в PNG.
И возможно помогут такие ответы на enSO: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338491/5308802) и [два](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1822423/5308802).

Comment: @AivanF - на счет первого варианта , да он работает отлично - НО! сохраняет только в ico формат, а мне нужно в png, на счет второго варианта - ДА! то что мне нужно - но я не могу скомпилировать этот код, проблема с функцией "SHCreateStreamOnFile" и еще много проблем, я уже какие-только библиотеки не подключал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А теперь еще один способ по сложнее, но он лучше нижеупомянутого тем, что иконка сохраняется в 32 битном формате с альфаканалом:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )
#include <string>

#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Shlwapi" )

#include <commoncontrols.h>
#include <comip.h>
#include <comdef.h>

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IImageList, __uuidof(IImageList));

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
    UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

    ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = nullptr;

    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure

    pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (pImageCodecInfo == nullptr)
        return -1;  // Failure

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0)
        {
            *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
            free(pImageCodecInfo);
            return j;  // Success
        }
    }

    free(pImageCodecInfo);
    return -1;  // Failure
}

static CLSID g_pngClsid = GUID_NULL;

static HICON getShellIconByIndex(int shilsize, int iImage)
{
    IImageListPtr spiml;
    SHGetImageList(shilsize, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spiml));

    HICON hico;
    spiml->GetIcon(iImage, 0x00000001, &hico);
    return hico;
}

static HICON getShellIcon(int shilsize, const std::string& fname) {
    UINT flags = SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;
    SHFILEINFO fi = { 0 };
    HICON hIcon = NULL;

    if (SHGetFileInfo(fname.c_str(), 0, &fi, sizeof(fi), flags) != 0) {
        hIcon = getShellIconByIndex(shilsize, fi.iIcon);
    }

    return hIcon;
}

struct BITMAP_AND_BYTES {
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp;
    int32_t* bytes;
};

static BITMAP_AND_BYTES createAlphaChannelBitmapFromIcon(HICON hIcon) {

    // Get the icon info
    ICONINFO iconInfo = { 0 };
    GetIconInfo(hIcon, &iconInfo);

    // Get the screen DC
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);

    // Get icon size info
    BITMAP bm = { 0 };
    GetObject(iconInfo.hbmColor, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);

    // Set up BITMAPINFO
    BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = bm.bmWidth;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bm.bmHeight;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // Extract the color bitmap
    int nBits = bm.bmWidth * bm.bmHeight;
    int32_t* colorBits = new int32_t[nBits];
    GetDIBits(dc, iconInfo.hbmColor, 0, bm.bmHeight, colorBits, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Check whether the color bitmap has an alpha channel.
    // (On my Windows 7, all file icons I tried have an alpha channel.)
    BOOL hasAlpha = FALSE;
    for (int i = 0; i < nBits; i++) {
        if ((colorBits[i] & 0xff000000) != 0) {
            hasAlpha = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If no alpha values available, apply the mask bitmap
    if (!hasAlpha) {
        // Extract the mask bitmap
        int32_t* maskBits = new int32_t[nBits];
        GetDIBits(dc, iconInfo.hbmMask, 0, bm.bmHeight, maskBits, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        // Copy the mask alphas into the color bits
        for (int i = 0; i < nBits; i++) {
            if (maskBits[i] == 0) {
                colorBits[i] |= 0xff000000;
            }
        }
        delete[] maskBits;
    }

    // Release DC and GDI bitmaps
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    ::DeleteObject(iconInfo.hbmColor);
    ::DeleteObject(iconInfo.hbmMask);

    // Create GDI+ Bitmap
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, bm.bmWidth * 4, PixelFormat32bppARGB, (BYTE*)colorBits);
    BITMAP_AND_BYTES ret = { bmp, colorBits };

    return ret;
}

static void saveFileIconAsPng(int shilsize, const std::string& fname, const std::string& pngFile) {

    HICON hIcon = getShellIcon(shilsize, fname);
    BITMAP_AND_BYTES bbs = createAlphaChannelBitmapFromIcon(hIcon);

    IStream* fstrm = NULL;
    SHCreateStreamOnFileA(pngFile.c_str(), STGM_WRITE | STGM_CREATE, &fstrm);
    bbs.bmp->Save(fstrm, &g_pngClsid, NULL);
    fstrm->Release();

    delete bbs.bmp;
    delete[] bbs.bytes;
    DestroyIcon(hIcon);
}
```

Использовать так:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &g_pngClsid);

    saveFileIconAsPng(SHIL_JUMBO, "Путь до нужного файла", "Конечное имя файла, например test.png");

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, кому интересно - самый простой вариант сохранить иконку в png формат:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "gdiplus" )
#include <string>

using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;

void SaveIconFromFileTo_PNGFormat(const std::string& strFileName, const std::wstring& where_to_save) {

    SHFILEINFO sfi{};

    SHGetFileInfo(strFileName.c_str(), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_LARGEICON);

    if (sfi.hIcon) {

        Bitmap* pBitmap = Bitmap::FromHICON(sfi.hIcon);

        CLSID encoderClsid;

        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoderClsid);

        pBitmap->Save(where_to_save.c_str(), &encoderClsid, NULL);
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;

ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

GetFileIcon("Путь до нужного файла", "Конечное имя файла, например test.png");

GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Так же можно указать другой формат для сохранения, указать нужно вот в этой функции GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &encoderClsid);, список ключей смотреть на msdn.